# Execute a command using popen

Tags: c++, perl, diff, popen

I have a C++ program in which I want to execute the following command:

```
cmd = "(diff <(perl -ne 's/^\\S+\\s//; if ((/aaa/ .. /bbb/) && /ccc/)"
            " { print \"$_\"}' file1)"
            "<(perl -ne 's/^\\S+\\s//; if ((/aaa/ .. /bbb/) && /ccc/)"
            " { print \"$_\"} file2)) ";
```

I get this error when I want to execute this command:

```
Search pattern not terminated at -e line 1.
```

I've noticed that the following commands work like this:

```
cmd = "diff <(echo aa) <(echo bb)"
string strCall = "bash -c \"( " + cmd + " ) 2>&1\"";
stream = popen(strCall.c_str(),"r"); // doesn't work popen(**str**.c_str(),"r")
```

and an example perl command containing '"' works like this:

```
cmd = "perl -ne '{print \"$1\"}' file"
stream = popen(str.c_str(),"r"); // doesn't work  popen(**strCall**.c_str(),"r");
```

but if the perl command doesn't contains '"', it works both ways:

```
cmd = "perl -ne '{print $1}' file"
string strCall = "bash -c \"( " + cmd + " ) 2>&1\"";
stream = popen(str.c_str(),"r"); // also works popen(**strCall**.c_str(),"r");
```

How can I do to use both diff and perl in the same command. I assume I have to use strCall.
I've tried also to escape the perl cmd like this, but it doesn't work:

```
cmd = "perl -ne '{print \\\"$1\\\"}' file" // one '/' for '/', one for "'" and one for '"'.
```

Also it didn't worked this, but I am however not allowed to use R("str"):

```
cmd = R"(perl -ne '{print \"$1\"}' file)"
string strCall = "bash -c \"( " + cmd + " ) 2>&1\"";
stream = popen(strCall.c_str(),"r")
```

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if it is a transposition error, but it looks like you might be missing a closing single quote on the second perl subshell. I assume you have this working on the command line?

Comment: Worked in cmd. It is a transposition error.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am not answering your question, but a common solution once you reach this many levels of quoting is to write a simple shell script and then call that from popen.

E.g., popen("/path/diffscript.sh", "r");